# oEmbed fails half of the times. Could I reload the request on fail?

Tags: oembed

I'm developing a site where I'm using oEmbed through Advanced Custom Fields, to display vimeo-videos. This is major feature for the site, and one of the clients requests is that he/she needs to be able to update the site with new content, with ease. Which is why I'm using ACF and oEmbed.

However, I noticed that there is a 50% chance that the oEmbed fails and will only output the hyperlink. This is not acceptable and I need to find a solution. And I thought that maybe I could find some help here.

Could I potentially refresh the oEmbed requests until it successfully loads, through javascript?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a work-around that works just as good, it functions and it's still easy for the end-client to update.

The problem seems to lie within Advanced Custom Fields's oEmbed function. First, I created a field with the type of "oEmbed" (PRO-version only), where I would later in the post just copy and paste the vimeo-link of my choosing. And as I stated before, it fetched the video around 50% of every on-site refresh.

However, as I looked around and realized that WordPress do have these embed features already built into it; I thought I could just as well create another field, but with the type of "Wysiwyg Editor" instead, and paste the url in that field and see what happens.

The result: I've loaded the page around 50 times now and it loads correctly every time.